# Why is the "download" in html not working?

Tags: html

I have started learning HTML today, and I came across a problem...

```html
<a href="html5icon.png" download>HTML Favicon</a>
<a href="mailto:randomemail@gmail.com">Email Me</a>
```

In, the first  tag, on clicking "HTML Favicon" in the webpage, Chrome(as well as Edge) just opens the image in a new tab and doesn't download it, as it is supposed to do.

In the second  tag, on clicking "Email me", nothing happens. No Outlook/Microsoft Mail opens asking me to write the email. However, on right-click, I do get a option to copy the email address.

Why are these occurring? In my [Instructors](https://youtu.be/kUMe1FH4CHE?t=4958) video, it seems that the problem doesn't occur. So, why does the problem occur to me?

---

Note:

1. I have both the files in the same folder <kbd>C:\Users\User-one\Desktop\Codes\Web\html</kbd>
2. I tried using Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome and the problem is there in both of the browsers
3. I haven't hosted the webpage or something like that... It's just a normal .html file

I asked Chatgpt, and it asked me to change browsers, keep the files in the same folder. I did those and it didn't work. It also said some other things, which, I couldn't make a head or tail of...

Comment: No it isn't what I am exactly looking for...

Comment: @PeterB Nope... they are suggesting JS ways to solve the problem...but I want to do it with html